# MaterialAutoCompleteTextView popup behind keyboard

Tags: java, android

In my fragment popup from MaterialAutoCompleteTextView start from bottom when keyboard is shown.

[Only first element are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqp94.png)

that my xml description

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/autoComplete_input_layout"
            style="@style/autocompleteLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/kis_input_autoComplete_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:completionThreshold="0"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:dropDownAnchor="@id/autoComplete_input_layout"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

my activity

```
        <activity android:name="com.mobile.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

editext is well shown above the keyboard

Don't know what i'm doing wrong with it :/

try to add
`this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`
but nothing change